# How to disable keyboard hide on touching outside of textfield in iOS app using ionic 2/3

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I want to disable keyboard hide when touching outside of textfield in iOS application which is build by using ionic. I want to hide keyboard by using only keyboard return button. Is there any way to disable keyboard hide on touching outside textfield?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false"/>
```

in your config.xml if you want to call focus() on iOS.

Then create directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[autofocuser]' 
})
export class Autofocuser {

    constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        let el = this.element.nativeElement.children[0]
        el.addEventListener('blur', (event) => {
            this.stopBubble(event);
            this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(el, 'focus', []);
        });
    }

    stopBubble(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        event.stopPropagation(); //Stops event bubbling
    }

}
```

Mark your input field with the directive.

See https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-keyboard/issues/81.

Answer (score -1):

check this [Doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/).

Install this below plugin

```
 ionic cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard

 npm install --save @ionic-native/keyboard
```

inside your html page.

```
<ion-input type="text" (blur)="closeKeyboard()"></ion-input>
```

inside your ts file

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

constructor(private keyboard: Keyboard) { }

closeKeyboard(){
  this.keyboard.close();
  (or)
  this.keyboard.open();
}
```

it will close the keyboard when you touch outside the keyboard

Update try using this in your input

```
(mousedown)="something(); $event.preventDefault()"
```

Comment: i want to disable keyboard close when user touch outside textfield